# I am comparing two dates. i want through error msg if user selected date is greater than current date

Tags: angularjs

I want compare two dates, user selected date with current date, i want through a error msg if user selected date is greater than current date

here is the my code i am trying but not able get error msg.

html

controller

```
$scope.age18Checking = function () {
      var userDate = new Date($scope.dateOfBirth);

          var year = userDate.getFullYear();
          var month = userDate.getMonth() + 1;
          var day = userDate.getDate();


         var userFullDate = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
         console.log("........User Date",userFullDate);

         var systemDate = new Date();
            console.log(".....systemDate",systemDate);

        if(systemDate.getTime() -18 > userFullDate.getTime()) {

            console.log("Is greater") 

        } 
    }
```

Thanks,
Zameer

Comment: You have not added html code

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Hi Agam, I want through error msg to user, if user selected date is greater than current date

Answer (score 1):

By the name of your function I assume that you want to check if current date - 18years is greater than users birthday? 
I would say that problem is that you're doing `getTime() - 18`, which only takes 18 milliseconds away from current time instead of 18 years.

Try this:

```
$scope.age18Checking = function () {
  var userDate = new Date($scope.dateOfBirth);

      var year = userDate.getFullYear();
      var month = userDate.getMonth() + 1;
      var day = userDate.getDate();


     var userFullDate = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
     console.log("........User Date",userFullDate);

     var systemDate = new Date();
     systemDate.setFullYear(systemDate.getFullYear() - 18)
        console.log(".....systemDate",systemDate);

    if(systemDate.getTime() > userFullDate.getTime()) {

        console.log("Is greater") 

    } 
}
```

Comment: I am not checking age, i am comparing two dates, which is user selected date and current date, if user selected date is greater than current date, this scenorio i want through a error msg.

Answer (score 1):

If You are calculating age then this should help you

```
 $scope.age18Checking = function () {
 var userDate = new Date($scope.dateOfBirth);

 var year = userDate.getFullYear();
 var month = userDate.getMonth();
 var day = userDate.getDate();

 var userFullDate = new Date(year,month,day);
 console.log("........User Date",userFullDate);

 var systemDate = new Date();
 console.log(".....systemDate",systemDate);

 if(systemDate.getTime() < userFullDate.getTime()) {

    console.log("Date of Birth cannot be greater than current Date");
    return false; 
 }  
 var age= userFullDate.getFullYear() - systemDate.getFullYear();
 var m= systemDate.getMonth() - userFullDate.getMonth();
 if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && systemDate.getDate() < userFullDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
}   
console.log("Current Age : "+age);
 if(age>=18)
 {
  console.log("Age is greater than or equal to 18");
  return true;
 }else
 {
  console.log("Age is less than 18");
  return false;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/) library, it is widely used to handle `Date` in Javascript, and is only `16.6kb`.

```
$scope.checkIncorrectDateSelected = function(){
  var userDate = new Date($scope.dateOfBirth);
  var now = moment();
  var userMoment = moment(userDate);
  if(now.diff(userMoment, "days", true) < 0){ //Will be true if user > now
    alert("Picked wrong date!");
  }
}
```

If you are also counting time, you should change `"days"` to `"seconds"` to be completely sure.